# Ajax with Python as backend

Tags: php, python, ajax, google-app-engine

I'm currently working on a web application, hosted on Google App Engine with the back-end written in Python. Now I feel the need to add Ajax-like features into my website. When I went through some of the Ajax tutorials on the internet, I found that all of them taught in context to having the back-end written in PHP.

So my question is, can't I use Ajax-like features on my application written in Python, hosted on Google App Engine? And if yes, can someone suggest some good tutorials for learning Ajax which uses Python as the back-end example?

EDIT: I'm using webapp2 framework, and am not familiar with Django.

Comment: Here is a video tuturial using app engine, webapp2, Python, Ajax, jquery and json : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkddK0Rd7nA

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is perfectly possible to do this.

A popular construction in new apps these days is running a "one page application", together with a 'completely separate' backend application providing an API.

The web page, with client-side javascript, effectively becomes its own client. It then talks (most commonly over JSON) to the server.

For example, one might construct a client-side application with [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/), and let to talk to a [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/) backend using some sort of [Restful API plugin](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to make things super easy to construct. The client and server would communicate over AJAX JSON requests / responses.

[Here's an example app](https://github.com/rxl/angular-flask) I quickly found of someone implementing such a thing.

Of course Angular and Flask are not the only technology choices you can make, there are plenty of others as well.

Answer (score 1):

The backend is irrelevant when doing Ajax. You could write it in PHP, Python, or even COBOL if that's what floats your boat. The main thing is that your Javascript is asynchronously requesting data, and that your backend is providing it in the format your frontend expects. These days, that's mostly JSON. Python is of course perfectly capable of providing JSON data (via the `json` module from the standard library).

Comment: so how should I proceed with learning Ajax with Python as my backend? Those tutorials don't seem to teach that with context to Python at the back

Comment: I don't know what tutorials you are looking at, but I'm finding it hard to understand what the problem is. If you know how to return a response from your webapp2 site, then you know all you need to as far as the backend is concerned: it's just the Javascript part you need to learn.

Comment: Any good tutorial I should learn the Javascript part? TheNewBoston tutorial states PHP as a prerequisite for learning Ajax for example.

Answer (score -1):

If your are using Django, you can read this 
https://racingtadpole.com/blog/django-ajax-and-jquery/

The important part is to use the {% csrf_token %}